# Concate string and variable in the batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, string-concatenation

I am new to batch file and need some help how to concate the variable and string in the batch file.
Just to give background I am parsing an yaml file and trying to get the last line of the yaml file in the variable(Var1) which holds the version of the package and same should be added to the path variable

```
    @echo off

SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ ..\..\Config\files.yaml"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    set "var1=!var:*:=!"
    set "b=C:\Development\Amazon_"
    set "output=%b% _ %var1%"
    echo(!var!
    echo !b!
    echo !var1!
    echo !var1!>output.bat
    ENDLOCAL   
    
)
```

The contents of the yaml file are as below:

```
project_config: 2 # file format version
name:    XXX Project

    packages:
      - id:      ABCD
        version: v1.2
      - id:      XYZ
        version: v2.2
      - id:      PQRZ
        version: v5.58
      - id:      Amazon_server_provision
        version: v2021_03_02
```

**With my code snippet I want to have the output in output variable as C:\Development\Amazon_v2021_03_02** when I do echo of output varible here its not printing anything on screen

But with current code snippet, I am not able concate the string and the variable(output), and also I have one space( v2023_03_02) in the variable(var1) content which I am not able to remove which here its printing in another batch file(output.bat).

Can someone tell me, what is wrong here with this snippet.

Comment: Why did you not use ```!b! _ !var1!```?

Comment: Compo : Thanks for that input now, I used as you suggested, but I am not still able to remove the white space. Wit your suggestion I edited the line as set "output=!b!_!var1!", I am getting output as C:\Development\Amazon_ v2021_03_02, But I need is C:\Development\Amazon_v2021_03_02, can you suggested what else I am missing here

Comment: Your code sets `var` to `12:        version: v2021_03_02`, then to `       version: v2021_03_02` , then `var1` to ` v2021_03_02`. You could simply try `set "var1=!var1:~1"` to trim off the first character, or `set "var1=!var1: ="` to delete all spaces in `var1`. BUT `set "output=!b! _ !var1!"` would set a variable ``output` to `C:\Development\Amazon_ _ v2021_03_02` given the code you've posted and the mods you've stated you've made....